# Put item of QTreeWidgetItem into variable

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

This is the code that i do:

```
`void Tabella::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int risultato;
    risultato = ui->treeWidget->currentItem()->text(2);
    ui->out_3->setText(QString::number(risultato));

}`
```

Are the any ways to assign the code into variable? Like that?

P.S I'm new in QT, i worked with c++ and java.

Comment: Where's the problem? Couldn't you say that the compiler complained because you were trying to convert `QString` to `int`? Couldn't you read that error message and do something? Why do you need to go through `int`, anyway?

Comment: Realy, my problem is that i can put what i want in variable no the cast...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ui->out_3->setText(ui->treeWidget->currentItem()->text());
```

You make take a look at this [question](http://www.qtforum.org/article/35397/how-get-text-index-from-qtreewidget-selected-item-child.html?s=4a83ca1ea2a19c8dc73202c830bb5d07ef5c2873#post112389)